# Store different values only - Python 2.7 - re.search

Tags: python, python-2.7

The issue I am facing is I have a word doc that has the word "number" with a digital value assigned to it like the below example.

```
words number=1111 words bee words
words number=1111 words bee words
words number=2222 words bee words
number=2222 number=2222 words bee words
words number=3333 words bee words
words words words bee number=3333
words number=4444 words bee words
words bee words number=4444 words
words bee words number=4444 words
```

If I run the below script it prints this:

```
1111
1111
2222
2222
3333
3333
4444
4444
4444
```

But want it to do is print only the number value once, then move on to the next "number" If that "number" holds the same value then move to the next and print the value only if its different value.

Idealy this is the output the script should provide back:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

I would like for it to skip numbers that have same values

```
openfile = open("openfile.txt", "r") 
openfile = openfile.readlines()  

bee = "bee"

def testscript():     
    for line in openfile:
        match = re.search('number=(\d+)', line) 
        if match and bee in line:
            storedvalue = match.group(1) 
            print storedvalue

testscript()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the already seen values with these chanegs:

```
def testscript():     
    already_seen = set()
    for line in openfile:
        match = re.search('number=(\d+)', line) 
        if match and bee in line:
            storedvalue = match.group(1)
            if storedvalue not in already_seen:
                already_seen.add(storedvalue)
                print storedvalue
```

Comment: You need to surround _bee_ with quotes

Comment: @volcano, while I would agree that the OP should have quoted `bee` instead using it as a global, I would argue that it is in fact not *necessary* to quote it.  I avoided making those sorts of changes to the OP's code to try and preserve as much context as possible.

Comment: @StephenRauch, sorry, missed the definition